# Remove style from database (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on old database table where there are values that have CSS attached to it.

For example:

```
<font size="25">Select your gender?</font>

<font size="25">Select your country?</font>
```

Is there any way to remove all the styling at once besides removing it one at a time?

I want to remove `<font size="25"></font>` and just keep Select your gender

Thank you in advance!

Comment: as i understan, these are some column values right ? if yes then you can use UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET columnName = null WHERE YourCondition

Comment: Do you want to remove the `<font size="25">` and `</font>`? Just keep `Select your gender`?

Comment: @jarlh yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the aid of a Helper Function

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol varchar(max) )
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('1.<font size="25">Select your <b>gender</b>?</font>')   -- Notice nested tags <b> ..</b>
,('2.<font size="25">Select your <span style="color:blue;">country</span>?</font>')

Select B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select NewStr = Stuff((Select '' +RetVal 
                                         From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract](SomeCol,'>','<') 
                                         Order By RetSeq
                                         For XML Path ('')),1,0,'')
              ) B
```

**Returns**

```
NewStr
1.Select your gender?
2.Select your country?
```

**The function if interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delim1 varchar(100),@Delim2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
                  ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
            From  ( values (convert(xml,'<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delim1,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>').query('.'))) as A(XMLData)
            Cross Apply XMLData.nodes('x') AS B(i)
          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1
)
/*
Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but zip's answer solved my issue.

Comment: @Peter Your call, but this will handle multiple records with and without nested tags.

Comment: Peter, its worth paying attention to the solution form @John as it fixes one worry I mentioned in my answer

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I was looking for a quick solution but the solution you have provided is worth learning which will help me in the future. Thank you

Comment: @Peter I created that function because I was tired of extracting strings (left, right, patindex, charindex, ... )  So I modified my split function to accept two non-like delimiters.  I have found numerous uses for it.   Hope it helps  :)

Answer (score 1):

A combination of charindex, substring and left can help
The problem is you have be sure that the data you need for every row is in the form:
xxxxx>DATA<*****, that you don,t a row in a form like xxxxx>DATA1<*****xxxxx>DATA2<*****

variable example:

```
declare @string as varchar(1000)  
declare @NoLeft as varchar(1000)  
declare @NoRight as varchar(1000)  
set @string = '1.<font size="25">Select your gender?</font>';
select @string
SELECT @NoLeft = substring(@string, CHARINDEX( '>', @string) + 1 , len(@string)-CHARINDEX( '>', @string))
select @NoLeft
SELECT @NoRight = left(@NoLeft, CHARINDEX( '<', @NoLeft) - 1)
select @NoRight
```

For a table it becomes

```
select left(substring(ColumnName, CHARINDEX( '>', ColumnName) + 1 , len(ColumnName)-CHARINDEX( '>', ColumnName)), CHARINDEX( '<', substring(ColumnName, CHARINDEX( '>', ColumnName) + 1 , len(ColumnName)-CHARINDEX( '>', ColumnName))) - 1)
From TableName
```

Comment: Thank you, this one helped!